# Using Kusto Query compare a time offset to current data set and calculate the difference

Tags: azure, kql, appinsights

I'm trying to figure out how to compare a current data set for the previous 24 hours to a -7d offset and then display the difference in a percentage. I currently have the following :

```
let currentB =
    requests
    | where Role == "tech"
    | where success == true
    | where name in ("POST /Auto", "POST Data/Play")
    | summarize request_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 5m);

let OffsetB=
    requests
    | where Role == "tech"
    | where success == true
    | where name in ("POST /Auto", "POST Data/Play")
    | where timestamp >= ago(8d) and timestamp < ago(7d)
    | summarize request_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 5m);
```

I'm not sure if I need to first format the dates to show only HH:MM or if I can union them and then compare ?

The result set of both queries returns as follows

| Timestamp | requestcount |
| --- | --- |
| 14/03/2024, 10:00:00.000 | 6 |

| Timestamp | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 07/03/2024, 10:00:00.000 | 2 |

What i'm trying to achieve is

| time | currentB | OffsetB | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 6 | 2 | 200% |

I've tried to Union and join but not sure I'm fully understanding it, I've also attempted to format the data and project after the summarize but this then just gets me 24 hours of info and not the current 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the timestamp value from `offsetB` dataset by adding 7 days. Join both datasets using inner join based on the matching timestamp value. Then find the difference between both the values and find the difference percentage.

**Code:**

```
let currentB =
    requests
    | where Role == "tech"
    | where success == true
    | where name in ("POST /Auto", "POST Data/Play")
    | summarize currentB_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 5m);
let OffsetB=
    requests
    | where Role == "tech"
    | where success == true
    | where name in ("POST /Auto", "POST Data/Play")
    | where timestamp >= ago(8d) and timestamp < ago(7d)
    | summarize OffsetB_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 5m);
    | extend timestamp=timestamp+7d;
currentB
| join kind=inner OffsetB on timestamp
| project currentB=currentB_count, OffsetB=OffsetB_count, PercentageDifference = (currentB_count - OffsetB_count)*100 / OffsetB_count
```

**Output**

| currentB | OffsetB | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2 | 200% |

Comment: Thanks Aswin, I'm not entirely sure on how that is working but if I look for example at currentB  vs OffsetB values independently I receive the following 

timestamp                          | CurrentB
14/03/2024 12:05:00:000   | 42
14/03/2024 12:00:00:000   | 20

timestamp                          | OffsetB
07/03/2024 12:05:00:000   | 20
07/03/2024 12:00:00:000   | 22

I don't think the Join you recommended is working as intended as I receive what looks to be just random comparisons of the data sets

Ideally I'd like to have just the hour and the two data sets (current vs offset)

Comment: Do you want to join the rows from both datasets based on the matching time value?

Comment: Yes, I'm effectively trying to compare the values
So I want to compare the value at timestamp

14/03/2024, 12:45:00.000 vs 
07/03/2024, 12:45:00.000